# Getting `GLIBC_2.32' and `GLIBC_2.34' not found in Jenkins (Docker) with DinD on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, docker-compose, docker-in-docker

I am trying to configure Jenkins as docker container with docker-in-docker on an EC2 instance running Ubuntu 22.04 but I am getting `GLIBC_2.32' and 'GLIBC_2.34' not found when I try to run a script containing docker command using docker plugin in Jenkins. I have followed [this](https://www.tiuweehan.com/blog/2020-09-10-docker-in-jenkins-in-docker/) as reference for setting Jenkins on my localhost. When moved to remote, I get these errors

```
...
$ docker login -u username -p ******** https://registry.gitlab.com
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by docker)
...
```

Here is the docker-compose.yaml file

```
version: '3.3'

services:
  docker-in-docker-container:
    image: docker:dind
    container_name: docker-in-docker-container
    user: root
    privileged: true
    expose:
      - 2375
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/jenkins_home
    environment:
      DOCKER_TLS_CERTDIR: ""
    restart: on-failure

  jenkins-container: 
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17
    container_name: jenkins-container
    user: root
    depends_on:
      - docker-in-docker-container
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/jenkins_home
      - /usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker
    environment:
      DOCKER_HOST: tcp://docker-in-docker-container:2375
    restart: on-failure
```

I tried to use various images from the Jenkins docker repository like alpine, jdk8, jdk11, and jdk17, but no luck.

Here is ldd info for troubleshooting from host machine

```
ubuntu@ip-10-0-0-251:~$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.35-0ubuntu3) 2.35
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Here is ldd info for Jenkins container

```
root@a2da70fc6100:/# ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u3) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

Looking forward to any help! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you're suspecting, you've having shared-library issues because you're injecting a `docker` binary that depends on a different version of GNU libc than exists in the image.

Injecting a `docker` binary like this isn't especially reliable due to issues like this.  In theory you could work around it by building a custom image that installed the required versions of the shared libraries, but if you're doing that, it's easier and safer to install the `docker` CLI tool in the image.  (Running the Docker daemon has complex requirements, but the CLI tool itself doesn't depend on anything other than access to a Docker socket.)  Also see the ["Installing more tools" section in the Jenkins image documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker/blob/master/README.md#installing-more-tools).

```bash
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts-jdk17
USER root
RUN apt-get update \
 && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    apt-get install --no-install-recommends --assume-yes \
      docker.io
USER jenkins
```

You do not need `EXPOSE`, `CMD`, or other setup; that all comes from the base image.

In the Compose file, add a `build:` line to build this custom image, delete the `image:` line, and delete the `volumes:` mounting the host's `/usr/bin/docker`.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jenkins-container:
    build: .
    # no image:
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/jenkins_home
      # but not /usr/bin/docker
```

Comment: This doesn't start the demon the image is not writable. Need `service docker start` but i am getting a `mkdir: cannot create directory ‘cpuset’: Read-only file system`

Answer (score 4):

Try UBUNTU 18.04LTS IT WILL WORK

Same error I got in Ubuntu 22.04lts on my Ec2 instance where I am trying to integrate docker to Jenkins container using docker runtime docker.sock by following command

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker  jenkins/jenkins:lts

docker exec -it -u 0 <container-id> bash

chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

It will allow docker runtime to integrate with jenkins

Tried docker pull

It threw me the same error

Getting `'GLIBC_2.32'` and `'GLIBC_2.34'` not found in Jenkins ( required by Docker)

The reason is Ec2 instance of
Ubuntu 22.04lts has GLIBC 2.35

check this command in ece instance

ldd --version

But inside instance jenkins container has GLIBC 2.31
CHECK

ldd --version
GLIBC 2.31

SO BECAUSE OF THIS DOCKER won't work inside that jenkins container in Ubuntu 22.04lts

Then I TRIED IN Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Use the same steps again

```
docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 50000:50000 -v jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/dock jenkins/jenkins:lts

docker exec -it -u 0 <container-id> bash

chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now check docker pull...

It worked perfectly

Comment: Another option would be to delete -v $(which docker):/usr/bin/docker and install the correct docker version inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

use this dockerfile to install docker and dependencies

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:lts
MAINTAINER madhusudan reddy
USER root
RUN apt-get -y update; apt-get install -y sudo; apt-get install -y git wget
RUN echo "Jenkins ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >> /etc/sudoers
RUN wget http://get.docker.com/builds/Linux/x86_64/docker-latest.tgz
RUN tar -xvzf docker-latest.tgz
RUN mv docker/* /usr/bin/
USER Jenkins
```