# Got `GLIBC_2.32' and `GLIBC_2.34' not found in Jenkins (Docker) with docker socket mounted on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: linux, docker, containers, glibc, docker-in-docker

I am trying to mount docker into a docker container, it used to work with WSL on Windows, but now that I am on Linux (Ubuntu 22) I am having this error when trying to use docker from the container.

Output when using docker on the container

```
root@54346cba74f7:/# docker 
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.32' not found (required by docker)
docker: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.34' not found (required by docker)
```

Glibc version on the container

```
root@435a50db166b:/# ldd --version
ldd (Debian GLIBC 2.31-13+deb11u5) 2.31
```

The docker-compose

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  jenkins-controller:
    image: jenkinsci/jenkins
    user: root
    privileged: true
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "10380:8080"
      - "50000:50000"
    volumes:
      - "jenkins-controller:/var/jenkins_home"
      - "/usr/bin/docker:/usr/bin/docker"
      - "//var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"

volumes:
  jenkins-controller:
```

I have tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72992489/11578589) but it is not working, the output is now:

```
root@9452ea2f61e1:/home/jenkins# docker ps -a
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to start the docker daemon

```
sudo systemctl start docker
```